# Laravel : get statusText translated in failed validation response

Tags: laravel

When my validation fails, I get a `statusText` in English in the response: `Unprocessable Entity`. How to get the translated version (according to my `config.app.locale`) ?

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $attributes = [
        'last_name' => ['integer'],
        'first_name' => ['email']
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->user, $attributes);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the strings in different languages inside the `resources/lang` folder. Inside each language folder, there are a few files with the message of each topic. For example, validation messages are inside `validation.php`.

To have the messages in your language you just need to add the proper set up in the `locale` key inside the `config/app.php` file. After that create the  `validation.php` file inside your language folder in `resources/lang`.

For more info check the [Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization)

Comment: Actually, I have `laravel-lang` package installed and I have add `"Unprocessable Entity": "FOO"` to my `resources/lang/fr.json` file, but it's not being used in that case.